# gitweb current version make fails on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu

on ubuntu 12.04 LTS I tried to install gitweb (on 2012-06-05):
I did this:

- get it as snapshot

  http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tree;f=gitweb;h=b811d5a45d1a3d6f2d1101b383c99675e9323b7f;hb=HEAD

download snapshot to /sonstiges/pub/2012/git-b811d5a.tar.gz and unpack it

```
wf@capri:/sonstiges/pub/2012$ scp git-b811d5a.tar.gz wf@jolo:/tmp
git-b811d5a.tar.gz                            100%   77KB  76.5KB/s   00:00   
root@jolo:/usr/local/src# tar xvfz /tmp/git-b811d5a.tar.gz 
git-b811d5a/
git-b811d5a/INSTALL
git-b811d5a/Makefile
git-b811d5a/README
git-b811d5a/gitweb.perl
git-b811d5a/static/
git-b811d5a/static/git-favicon.png
git-b811d5a/static/git-logo.png
git-b811d5a/static/gitweb.css
git-b811d5a/static/gitweb.js
```

make copy of original

```
root@jolo:/usr/local/src/git-b811d5a# cp /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi /tmp
```

start make

```
make prefix=/usr gitweb                          
make gitwebdir=/usr/lib/cgi-bin install-gitweb
```

make fails:

```
root@jolo:/usr/local/src/git-b811d5a# make prefix=/usr gitweb 
    SUBDIR ../
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `GIT-VERSION-FILE'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `gitweb'.  Stop.
```

**What needs to be done to get make working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in 2012-06:

```
modify directory structure as in 
http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git

get GIT-VERSION--GEN from
http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;h=955b02b48032db91d80d8009da28e1d15099c56c;hb=f623ca1cae600e97cb0b38131fdd33e4fb669cf8

root@jolo:/usr/local/src/git# chmod +x GIT-VERSION--GEN 
root@jolo:/usr/local/src/git# ./GIT-VERSION--GEN
```

here is what I did in 2014-05:

```
sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
cd git 
sudo curl -O  http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;h=955b02b48032db91d80d8009da28e1d15099c56c;hb=f623ca1cae600e97cb0b38131fdd33e4fb669cf8
sudo chmod +x GIT-VERSION-GEN
sudo ./GIT-VERSION-GEN
sudo make prefix=/usr gitweb
sudo make gitwebdir=/usr/lib/cgi-bin install-gitweb
```

Comment: modify directory structure as in 
http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git means what ? I am getting the same issue

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue. Can you please explain in details.

Comment: see 2014-05 instructions - just tested a minute ago